# MongoDB loads of daily data (or stick with mysql?)

Tags: mysql, mongodb, nosql

In short, we have a business vehicle control via GPS currently working on mysql with a large volume of data. We are studying the possibility of moving to mongoDB as db but still do not see clear. Currently, we are testing with mongoHQ (daas mongoDB).

We have aprox 2000 gps sending information every minute with position, velocity and state. In one day, 24 hours, 1440 minutes, each gps sends 1440 tracks of information, so 1440tracks/device * 2000devices = 2.8M tracks / day.

Our **first idea** was to have a collection and store each track as a doc in this collection, but daily 2.8M generating tracks at the end of the month we have +-80M documents in a collection. We have to create daily, weekly or reports between dates, for example, if after 2 months of service, a client wants to see a report of 3 days, we would have to do a find of 1440 tracks/day * 3days inside about 160M documents ... how would be the response times? mongodb saturated? If multiple clients make similar requests at once, what would happen?

> NOTE: Each document occupies approx 0.3KB , whereby each GPS per day
>   occupies 0.3 * 1440 = 0.5MB , although greater storageSize ...

**Second idea** embedding.

Here we decided to group all the tracks on a daily document. Each has 1 gps doc / day and 1440 tracks of information are added $push into an array of tracks { }. Thus, each day we would have only 2k docs and by the end of the month just 60k instead of 80M! We thought 'we had found gold' until we realized that $pushing 1440 tracks inside each doc daily created  reallocation whereby each document takes much longer and is not viable .. How could we improve embedding ? If the first idea was generating about 1GB storage daily, with this is about 3GB...

With the first idea, track = doc, gps need 0.5MB each day (a little bit more storagesize), which would be about 1GB daily for 2000 teams. About 30 GB per month, even with the heaviest of mongohq plan (600GB) or mongolab (400GB), we would have a maximum of 20 months of service before reaching the limits ..
But the same in mysql after year and a half, we are not occupying more than 30GB .. :/

Currently, we do not see option to change and we have to stick with Mysql for now... any idea on how to make a good switch from mysql to nosql?

Comment: What's your reason for ditching MySQL in favor of MongoDB in the first place?

Comment: Scalability and good daas for mongoDB without having to spent too much time on creating a good mysql scalable structure! @Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to big data...

What we do is this:
We have a influx of log events at the rate of about 200 logs/sec.
These logs are put in a database.collection called `log.foo`.
You don't touch these records. Only new inserts are made here. NEVER EVER UPDATE THEM. It will lock your database and kill it's performance.

What you do is create a new database.collection called `aggregate.foo`. This is a new database because it will have its own write lock and will therefore not interfere with your log database.

Then you create a job that you run with cron or something similar. This job makes a query on `log.foo` for a given timeslice (ObjectId is very usefull for that). The job aggregates these lines as you see fit and puts new documents in `aggregate.foo`. Then you can choose to delete the rows from `log.foo` if you want, but storage is cheap, so why not keep them.

So essentially: combine your two ideas, but separate log insertion and aggregation.

Comment: That sounds good! Just one more q. you said storage is cheap, well it's not, not if I'm using mongohq / mongolab where 2GB are 15$ and 5GB 49$! Do you recommend me to run mongodb with a linux cloud server? Thanks!

Comment: Yea, that is expensive. We run on AWS. That has the advantage you can scale stuff exactly to your needs. Also you can push your redundent log files to AWS's glacier (tape storage) so you don't lose them.

Comment: Also I believe mongohq got hacked lately so I wonder if they could be trusted with your data....

Comment: True.. thinking of mongoLab though! Anyways, it's too expensive to store these amounts of data, using an EC2 linux centos would perform fine for mongodb? 'cause storing several GB's of info is supercheap in aws compared in mongohq/mongolab. Thanks!

Comment: one more point i would like to add here is i assume that granularity is not of importance far down the line, for example you may not really need a 1 min long from 1 year ago, store the aggregates in the second collection/table but keep the 1st one capped where only the inserts occur

Answer (score 1):

When you know that your documents will reach a certain size, you can avoid reallocation by prepopulating them at creation.

When you know that your array will eventually have exactly 1440 entries, you can create the document with 1440 dummy-entries with the same set of fields, all filled with placeholder data which has the same length as the real data. When you then gradually add the real data, you replace these entries with $set instead of using $push.

To improve the performance of reports which aggregate data of past days, you could run a MapReduce job every night to aggregate the relevant data of the day into a new collection.

Comment: Well, it's not always 1440 entries, some devices send info every 2 minutes which reduces it to 720, or sends some extra tracks like events, so it could be 720+-events (730-750) or 1440+events. How could I create dummy-entries that will have to be set by timestamp? Would it be good to create 1500 entries for each device/day and then $set them? That would create extra elements in the tracks array that could be deleted. Would it work?